# covert sqlite database in to csv format? and then mail this csv file in iPhone Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share all the data i have stored using sqlite database between two devices to reuse the data by dumping in another device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345690/how-to-share-all-the-data-i-have-stored-using-sqlite-database-between-two-device)

I want to **import a sqlite Database and save it as a CSV file** and **`then mail this file via email.`**

can i import **sqlite in to csv** format in iphone app programmatically to attach in mail composer

---

i used following functio to get the data base file

```
+(NSString*)getSqliteDBFile
{
      NSString *docsDirectoryPath;
      NSArray *dirPaths;
      NSString *databasePath;
      NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

      // Get the documents directory
      dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

      docsDirectoryPath = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
      NSLog(@"path :%@", docsDirectoryPath);

      // Build the path to the database file
      databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"LeadGenDB.sqlite"]];
      NSLog(@"path :%@", databasePath);


      return databasePath;
}
```

Now I nees to convert sqlite file to csv file

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's certainly doable, but the whole sequence would be quite a bit of code. StackOverflow is not here to provide complete solutions.

Comment: That is just getting the path, you will need to [query the database](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-selecting-data.html) and then put the results into a [CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159576/how-to-export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-iphone-sdk-3-0) <- not a complete solution but a good start. When you get stuck post a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not convert direct sqlite to csv. First you get your all database data and write into csv file.use below example for create csv and send it.

```
NSString *csvString =@"1,2 , 3 , 4, 5 ,6 , 7";

        for(int i=0;i<rangeData.count ;i++)
        {
            NSArray *temp = [di timeCalculation:[[rangeData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@""] :[[rangeData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@""]];



            NSString *strTemp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",

                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[simpleDate stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[rangeData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@""] floatValue]]]],
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[shrotDate stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[rangeData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@""] floatValue]]]],
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[shrotDate stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[rangeData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@""] floatValue]]]],
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[shrotDate stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[rangeData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@""] floatValue]]]],
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[shrotDate stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[rangeData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@""] floatValue]]]],

                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@": " withString:@""]] ,
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" : " withString:@""]]];
            csvString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@",csvString,strTemp];
        }

        //create instance of NSFileManager
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Document Dir: %@",documentsDirectory);

        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv", @"userdata"]]; //add our file to the path
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];


        NSData *csvData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]];
        [controller setSubject:@"CSV Export"];
        [controller setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO]; 
        [controller addAttachmentData:csvData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"userdata.csv"];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
```

Comment: here rangedata is the data array retrieved from atable in the my database right?

Comment: yes you use your own array for that.it is my demo example.